# React-native Axios status code response 0 (Skipped) when receive the response when the app at the background

Tags: ios, react-native, axios

I have to send an http request to the server, and the request takes up to 20 seconds, during this time I have to send my app to background and open another app to do something else and then get back to my App, and when I receive the response from the first app when it at the background, and return it to foreground, Axios returns response 0 (Skipped), while it passed from the server and it should be 200.

```
return Axios.post(url, payLoad)
            .then(result => {
                return handleSuccessResultCode(result);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log("AxiosPost-error", error);
                return handleResultCode(error, resolve, reject);
            });
```

Payload Header:

```
content-type: application/json
provider: ios
macaddress: <Device MAC>
deviceid: <Device ID>
```

Console.log prints:

```
AxiosPost-error Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at EventTarget.handleError (xhr.js:83)
    at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (event-target-shim.js:818)
    at EventTarget.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:574)
    at EventTarget.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:388)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:501
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:189)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:395)
    at MessageQueue.js:106
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:343)
```

**Response:**
response 200 if I received the http response when the app is in foreground.
response 0 if I received the http response when the app is in the background.

by the way, this issue happens only on regular devices, and it works correctly if I test it on simulator.

Comment: have you tried to check the behaviour using fetch instead of Axios? if yes, what it was?

Comment: yes I did, and it has the same behaviour. in addition I have added NSAllowsArbitraryLoads true to the inpho.plist.

Comment: Also I want to know what is the difference between simulator and regular device for this flow? simulator returns status 200, and regular device returns 0!